# How to explicitly invoke an action used by a form in Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application contains a form allowing user to select a Playground object to work with. Choosing playground updates current user's current_playground_id field. Main elements are:

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :users, :only=>[:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show, :index, :set_playground, :pass, :destroy] do
    member do
      patch :set_playground
      get :pass
    end
  end
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <!-- playground selection form -->
        <%= form_for(current_user, url: set_playground_user_path(current_user), method: :patch) do |f| %>
          <ul>
            <li><%= t('Playground') %>: <%= f.collection_select :current_playground_id, list_of_playgrounds, :id, :code  %> </li>
            <li class="actions" ><%= f.submit "OK" %></li>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def set_playground
    @user.updated_by = current_login
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'User switched playground.' }
       else
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Unable to switch playground.' }
      end
    end
  end
```

I wish to invoke the same set_playground action from playgrounds index view, so that the user can choose the playground he wants to work with from this point. I added a button_to invocation in the playgrounds index view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table table-striped">    
    <% @playgrounds.each do |object| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="col_narrow"> <%= image_tag object.logo if object.logo.attached? %> </td>
        <td class="col_narrow"> <%= link_to object.hierarchy, object %> </td>
        <td class="col_narrow"> 
          <%= object.translated_name %> 
          <%= button_to 'Select', [current_user, set_playground_user_path, object.id], method: :patch) %>  
        </td>
        <td class="col_wide"> <pre> <%= object.translated_description %> </pre> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried several syntaxes based on polymorphic urls methods or direct action call, but could not find the correct syntax to execute the set_playground method without generating an error. The example above returns:

> No route matches {:action=>"set_playground", :controller=>"users"},
>   missing required keys: [:id]

I'd be glad if you can propose a solution to achieve this!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `only:` option is just used to limit the default set of routes generated by `resources`. You could use `only: [:show, :index]` if you had a read only resource for example. Passing the full set of routes + your own custom routes is just nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route generated is:

```
/users/:id/set_playground
```

As you can see the only dynamic segment is the user id. If you want to pass the id of the playground you need to do it in the request body.

To link to this non-standard action with the polymorphic route helpers you want to use `[:set_playground, @user]` but you also need to set a param in the body:

```
<%= button_to 'Select', [:set_playground, @user], method: :patch, params: { current_playground_id: object.id }) %>
```

This adds a hidden input to the form.

See:

- [Creating Paths and URLs From Objects](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects)
- [button_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

Comment: Technically you could pass the `current_playground_id` as a query parameter - `/users/1/set_playground?current_playground_id=2` but its not the right way to do it.

Comment: As @user is not defined, I replace it by current_user (provided by Devise gem). But it fails in user_params definition with this message: param is missing or the value is empty: user

Comment: That means that `current_user` is nil. You have to add a condition surrounding the button which checks if there is a signed in user.

Comment: If you´re only setting it for the current user I would create a `PATCH /playgrounds/:id/set_current` route instead. Its a lot less awkward.

Comment: Actually, current_user is never nill, I checked it at the console. Passing parameters between classe instances may be over my competences ... So I applied your suggestion to set_current the playground instance. It works, but it means updating the current_user from the playground controller which frightens me a bit in an object world. (current playground is saved respectively in each users profile as its preferred playground). I will try to enhance the solution ... Thanks Max!

Comment: Ah, I completely missread your earlier comment "But it fails in user_params definition with this message: param is missing or the value is empty: user". That means you have a params whitelist that looks something like `params.require(:user)...` but since you are only using a single param you don't need to use strong parameters which is a safeguard against mass assignment. So you can do just do `@playground = Playground.find(params[:current_playground_id]); current_user.update(current_playground: @playground)` or you could nest the parameter by `params: { user: { current_playground_id: x } }`

Answer (score 0):

`set_playground` is a member path, not a collection path, so it needs the user's id, so the correct call to that path method is

```
set_playground_user_path(current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send user id to your set_playground_user function.
And if I understand your code you have to send current_playground_id too.
Maybe you can try something like :

```
<%= button_to 'Select', set_playground_user_path(id: current_user, current_playground_id: object.id), method: :patch) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have working code in your header, so you could probably more easily adapt that to send a specific option. The problem with a `button_to` is preparing the form-data (which a form does automatically obviously). But of course that is possible. So two options:

#### Use a fixed form

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table table-striped">    
    <% @playgrounds.each do |playground| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="col_narrow"> <%= image_tag playground.logo if playground.logo.attached? %> </td>
        <td class="col_narrow"> <%= link_to playground.hierarchy, playground %> </td>
        <td class="col_narrow"> 
          <%= playground.translated_name %>
          <%= form_for(current_user, url: set_playground_user_path(current_user), method: :patch) do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :current_playground_id, value: playground.id %>  
            <%= f.submit "Select" %>
          <% end %> 
        </td>
        <td class="col_wide"> <pre> <%= playground.translated_description %> </pre> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Build the form-data inside the button-to

If you want to use the button-to, you need to send the correct data along:

```
<%= button_to 'Select', [:set_playground, current_user], method: :patch, params: {user: { current_playground_id: playground.id }}) %>
```

(please note that `[:set_playground, current_user]` is identical to `set_playground_user_path(current_user)` so you can switch those if you want)

Also note that in both examples I replace your variable `object` by the more meaningful `playground`.